# c# xaml Managing many bindings(property of an array?)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to set up many bindings in a xaml page in a UWP c# project so I thought about binding to an array, however I can't figure out how to make this because the elements in a {x:Bind example} styled binding should be properties.

I know(is it correct?) that in c# it isn't possible to have a property linked to an array, I mean something like this(even if it isn't correct):

```
    Brush[] _myArray = new Brush[50];

    public Brush[n] myArray
    {
        get { return _myArray[n]; }

        set { _myArray[n] = value; }
    }
```

So I thought(it is a terrible solution) about declaring all of my variables and properties and then adding all the properties to a list and accessing them in c# as items of the list, something like this to be clear:

```
    Brush _myBrush1;
    public Brush myBrush1{...}
    List<Brush> myBrushList = new List<Brush>();

    private void initialize()
    {
        myBrushList.Add(myBrush1);
    }
```

But then with

```
    myBrushlist[0] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.red);
```

nothing happens, it's like I set the element of the list(and not the property) to be a new brush.

What's the right way to do this? If there isn't a "right way" How could I correct my code?

Comment: Are you trying to Get an Array of `Brush` es? to bind them to a List? Then your second option already adds the brushes. So what is the question here?

Comment: I want to bind the brushes to the background of some border elements in xaml, I add the properties to the list to be able to manage them with an index because it is not possible(at least I think) to bind an array and managing 50 or more variables, all with their own name would be a mess, however I'm not able of changing the value of the property with the sintax I showed before

Comment: Its not a good way to do the way you are doing. If you want to make a collection of Brushes( Like a Theme when changed you change the Border, Background, Foreground) of the controls, I suggest you use `ResourceDictionary` and then bind the Colors from `ResourceDictionary`. Search for `ResourceDictonary in UWP`, you will find lot of examples

Comment: You were right, I struggled a bit and studied the ResourceDictionaries in Detail and they are exactly what I was looking for beacuse they let you control properties by a key value that I'm using as an index because I needed to control properties depending on a given number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested the right way to do what I was looking for was using a resource dictionary, below some code:

xaml

```
...
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="n1" Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="n2" Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>
</Page.Resources>
...
<Grid Background="{StaticResource n1}"/>
<Grid Background="{StaticResource n2}"/>
```

c#

```
SolidColorBrush myResource= (SolidColorBrush)this.Resources["n" + Convert.ToString(myIndexInt)];
myResource.Color = Colors.Red;
```